# CarrierWaveでCrop処理をする際のversionsについて

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, carrierwave

下記環境で、アップロードした画像を任意の範囲でcroppingするための処理を実装していたのですが、メインの画像ファイルは意図した通りにcropできました。しかし、versionsでの処理が上手く行かなかったので質問させてください。

- Rails 4.2.1
- CarrierWave 0.10.0
- 試行するためのプロジェクトも公開しています。

  - https://github.com/kntmrkm/carrierwave_crop_example

### 詳細

アップロードした画像はversionを[:mobile]として別途processしているのですが、
croppingが適用されません。実現したいのはメインのアップロード画像と併せて[:mobile]バージョンもcroppingしたいのです。

#### Cropのための記述

app/uploaders/common_uploader.rb

```
class CommonUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  def cropper
    return unless model.send("#{mounted_as}_crop_x").present?
    manipulate! do |img|
      crop_x = model.image_crop_x.to_i
      crop_y = model.image_crop_y.to_i
      crop_w = model.image_crop_w.to_i
      crop_h = model.image_crop_h.to_i
      rotation = model.image_rotate.to_i
      crop_value = "#{crop_w}x#{crop_h}+#{crop_x}+#{crop_y}"

      img.rotate rotation
      img.crop crop_value
      img = yield(img) if block_given?
      img

    end
  end

end
```

app/models/user.rb

uploaders/に記述したcropperメソッド内ではattr_accessorの値が取得できないようです。
（https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17639405/carrierwave-attributes-that-are-not-in-the-database-is-always-equal-to-nil）

なので、他の情報を参考にafter_update時に、croppingメソッドから画像処理を呼び出すようにしました。

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :image, ::UserImageUploader

  attr_accessor :image_crop_x
  attr_accessor :image_crop_y
  attr_accessor :image_crop_w
  attr_accessor :image_crop_h
  attr_accessor :image_rotate

  after_update :cropping

  private
    def cropping
      if image_crop_x.present?
        image.process!
        #image.cropper

        #image.cache_stored_file!
        #image.retrieve_from_cache!(image.cache_name)
        #image.recreate_versions!
        #image.recreate_versions!
      end
    end
end
```

image.process!またはimage.cropperをuser.rb内のcroppingで実行するとcropされます。また、以下のように記述しても可能です。

```
image.cache_stored_file!
image.retrieve_from_cache!(image.cache_name)
image.recreate_versions!
```

しかし、`app/uploaders/user_image_uploader.rb`に記述している、[:mobile],[:thumb]のバージョンについてはcropできません。

```
class UserImageUploader < CommonUploader
  version :mobile do

  end
  version :thumb do
    process quality: 50
  end
end
```

以上が問題の内容なのですが、`image.recreate_versions!`を２度記述するとmobile,thumbのバージョンについてもcropされるようになります。しかし、この場合、外部ストレージの環境（S3など）の際に`NoMethodError - undefined method`content_length' for nil:NilClass:`が発生してしまいます。

どのように記述すればよいでしょうか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己回答です。

バックエンド側でcrop処理することをやめ、フロントエンドでcropした画像データを送ることにしました。

[FormDataを使わずにBlobをアップロード・inputタグに設定する方法はありますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/20169/formdata%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E3%82%8F%E3%81%9A%E3%81%ABblob%E3%82%92%E3%82%A2%E3%83%83%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89-input%E3%82%BF%E3%82%B0%E3%81%AB%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95%E3%81%AF%E3%81%82%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B)